# Control colour of geom_text_repel

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics, ggrepel

I would like to change the colour of one of my `ggrepel` labels to black. I have tried to override the inheritance by specifying `...geom_text_repel(...colour='black')` but that doesn't seem to work.

[image: uempmed is blue but I need it to match the black line colour]

My attempt at a fix to the problem is in the second `geom_text_repel` function (below).

N.B. If there is a way to control the colour of individual `geom_text_repel` elements, rather than having to call the function twice, I would prefer that.

```
library("tidyverse")
library("ggthemes")
library("ggrepel")

df1 <- gather(economics, variable_name, observation, -date) %>% 
  rename(period = date) %>% 
  filter(variable_name == 'psavert')

df2 <- gather(economics, variable_name, observation, -date) %>% 
  rename(period = date) %>% 
  filter(variable_name == 'uempmed')

ggplot(df1, aes(x = period, y = observation, colour = variable_name)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data = df2, colour = 'black', size = .8) +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = subset(df1, period == max(as.Date(period, "%Y-%m-%d"))),
    aes(label = variable_name),
    size = 3,
    nudge_x = 45,
    segment.color = 'grey80'
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = subset(df2, period == max(as.Date(period, "%Y-%m-%d"))),
    aes(label = variable_name, colour = 'black'), #How do I set the colour of the label text to black?
    size = 3,
    nudge_x = 45,
    segment.color = 'grey80'
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_color_tableau() + 
  scale_fill_tableau() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  labs(x="", y="", title = "Economic Data") + 
  scale_x_date(limits = c(min(df1$period), max(df1$period) + 1200))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do the same thing you did in your `geom_line()` layer. You want to set a color, not a mapping. Make `colour = 'black'` an argument to `geom_text_repel()`, not `aes()`.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = period, y = observation, colour = variable_name)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data = df2, colour = 'black', size = .8) + # just like this layer
  geom_text_repel(
    data = subset(df1, period == max(as.Date(period, "%Y-%m-%d"))),
    aes(label = variable_name),
    size = 3,
    nudge_x = 45,
    segment.color = 'grey80'
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = subset(df2, period == max(as.Date(period, "%Y-%m-%d"))),
    aes(label = variable_name) # don't assign it here, 
    size = 3,
    nudge_x = 45,
    segment.color = 'grey80',
    colour = "black" # assign it here
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_color_tableau() + 
  scale_fill_tableau() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  labs(x="", y="", title = "Economic Data") + 
  scale_x_date(limits = c(min(df1$period), max(df1$period) + 1200))
```

Note that now the first line AND text are now both set manually to `"black"`, so the automatic variable assignment will start over with next line (and text).  If you want to set that manually to a different color, you can use the same strategy (set it as an argument to the `geom`, not as an argument to `aes`

[image]